# Grails redirect redirects to invalid location

Tags: grails, controller

I'm running my app in development environment. 
Using this simple controller:

```
class MyController {

  def index() {
    redirect uri: '/'                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  }
}
```

I'm getting redirected to `http://localhost:8080/[:]/` location for some reason.
`$appName` seems good inside Config.groovy. `grails.serverURL` looks also OK.
What's the problem?

**UPDATE 1**

I'm using grails 2.2.4

**UPDATE 2**

The problem is with invalid `grails.serverURL` value. When I'm debugging the app, it has a correct value inside Config.groovy. When I'm printing out this value from servlet method it's set to `http://localhost:8080/[:]/` for some reason. I'm using `Spring Security Core 1.2.7.3` and `Spring Security UI 0.2`, I think that for some reason grails.serverURL is overwritted inside this plugin. 
How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple. I've included `MyConfig.groovy` inside `Config.groovy` like this:

```
grails.config.locations = [ "classpath:${appName}-config.properties",
                            "classpath:${appName}-config.groovy",
                            MyConfig,                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                            "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.properties",
                            "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.groovy"]
```

there was also `environments.production`, `environments.development` and `environments.test` sections however, `$appName` is undefined there. I've removed setting of `grails.serverURL` from `MyConfig.groovy` and its worked now.